# Retry logic app with same Service bus queue item

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

Trigger used - when message is received in a queue(auto-complete)
When HTTP action fails, i need to re process the whole flow with same queue item/queue message.
Is this possible, if yes any resource or any workaround would help

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger your logic app with the same queue message, just add a `condition` action to determine weather your `Http` action is success or failed based on the `Status code`.

I designed a logic app workflow for you:

[image]

Assuming that your `Http` action returns a success code of 200, you can continue to process the original process, if not, you can use the `Send message` action to resend the received message to the queue, which can trigger your logic app again

Comment: Thanks got a way to proceed further

Comment: I would be careful with this approach, if there is a corrupt message you could end up with an endless loop with no way to clear this up.